# Concept of Free Will

Tags: brain, free-will

I was not really sure which stack exchange to post this question, however, this one suits well I am guessing.

So assuming that the brain is just a carbon-based input/output calculator, and assuming most of the signals and connections between the nerves are deterministic.

Every outgoing action(output) of someone is determined via the ingoing actions (inputs) with some kind of connection/calculation done by the brain. So if this hypothesis is true, How can someone prove or argue of the existence of the free will?

Isn't it possible if we determine every aspect of the input signal, and if we know what the brain does with this input (via some computer model, or something with same manner), can't we foresee what that person is about to do or act versus the input action?

If the statement above is true and is proved, can't we say the concept of free will is dead? and can't we read minds?

I am looking for any kind (technical or hypothetical) of an answer to disprove the idea written above. Ty

Comment: Welcome to the site oakca, please take the [tour] and read up in our help centre about how we work: [ask] We have a one question - one best answer model on SE. You've written multiple questions, you can [edit] to fit in with the rules in the [help] centre, or the question will get closed. Also, you seemed to have made assumptions which can't be justified in light of modern thought, we expect you to have done some research on the subject before posting. Your question (after editing) might be more suited to [philosophy.se] .